# what account does code run under in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

If i create a custom web part which account does it run under when a user navigates to page that has the custom web part added.  Is it the app pool account or the users account.  I cant remember the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code will run under user credentials until you use Elevated security privileges which will force code to run under application pool account.

Comment: But the code runs in w3p process and the w3p user is the apppoolaccount name. Doesn't it mean that in share point code runs as w3p user and the share point user is only used to validate credentials to check if he has access to the Web part?